# Content of QAxWidget disappears when not in focus

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, activex

I am currently exploring the possibilities of building a GUI that can directly interact with and display PowerPoint-presentations. For that I am using Python and PyQt5 on a windows machine with PowerPoint installed. The PowerPoint-presentation is embedded inside a `QAxWidget` and generally works as intended.

Unfortunately there is a small but hugely annoying bug that I haven't yet found a solution for. When the focus is not set on the `QAxWidget`, the content disappears until I click into the `QAxWidget` again.

Here's a gif that showcases this by clicking into other GUI elements:
[image: QAXWidget-content disappearing up]

I've already learned about `setFocus()`, but that doesn't seem to be applicable here.
Also I've looked into a couple of Qt-development-books for Python and C++, but I haven't found a single one working with ActiveX controls and `QAxWidget`s. Any research material working with `QAxWidget`s, ActiveX, anything that might suit my needs, is also highly appreciated. Only research material I am aware of is the C++ reference and posts on forums.

With the following minimal example code and the requirements stated in the beginning, you should be able to reproduce what I've shown in the GIF:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QAxContainer import QAxWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QApplication, QMainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.menuBar().addMenu("&About")

        self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.centralwidget_vlayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)

        self.axwidget = QAxWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.axwidget.installEventFilter(self)
        self.axwidget.setControl(r"C:\path\to\presentation.pptx")

        self.pushbutton = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushbutton.setText("Press me!")

        self.centralwidget_vlayout.addWidget(self.axwidget)
        self.centralwidget_vlayout.addWidget(self.pushbutton)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.show()

    def eventFilter(self, widget: QWidget, event: QEvent):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Resize and widget is self.axwidget:
            self.axwidget.setFixedHeight(int(self.axwidget.width() / 16 * 9))

        return super(MainWindow, self).eventFilter(widget, event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Now to the main question: How can I make sure that the PowerPoint-presentation is visible at all times, even when the focus is set to another GUI-element?

Comment: I'd suggest to start with a very basic layout: just a box layout with the QAxWidget and any widget that could accept focus (buttons, line edits, etc). If that still happens, then provide *that* as an example code (remember that we should always try to provide a [mre]), if it doesn't, then you can slowly reintegrate your current code and find when the problem begins to happen, and *then* you either will have found the cause, or you'll be able to provide a more appropriate MRE.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for pointing that out, I just provided a MRE. Unfortunately the same behaviour can be seen here aswell, I also updated the GIF. Generally I start to feel like what I wanna build can't or shouldn't be done. At least with my set goals of using Python and PyQt5. There is really weird behaviour going on I just do not understand. If you remove the line `self.menuBar().addMenu("&About")`, which has nothing to do with the `QAxWidget`, the presentation doesn't get displayed and the `QAxWidget` remains all white. Clicking into it also doesn't reveal when the `.addMenu()` is missing.

Comment: @musicamante But that's besides the point, I'd be happy to find a way to always have this PowerPoint.Application-COM-Object actively displayed in the `QAxWidget`.

Comment: Unfortunately, as previously mentioned, I cannot test your code as I don't use Windows. That said, let's try to remove any potential culprit; for instance, to understand the menu issue, try with a basic QWidget instead, and also try to add an action to the menu (empty menus are not really a good thing) or disable it; then, don't create the QAxWidget with a parent (let the layout/parent widget do that) and do `setControl()` only after that (for example, after `setCentralWidget()`). I don't think that would change much, but that's not impossible.

Comment: @musicamante I highly regard your correspondence, unfortunately none of the above worked. After being clueless for a bit, I decided to test displaying a PDF-file instead.

`self.axwidget = QAxWidget("Microsoft Web Browser")
        self.axwidget.installEventFilter(self)
        self.axwidget.dynamicCall("Navigate(const QString&)", r"C:\path\to\doc.pdf")`

With the PDF there are no issues when clicking on the button below, the PDF remains visible. I am also able to remove the menubar. I wonder if it has something to do with the controller the pptx-file uses.

Comment: It certainly does: as I mentioned in your previous post, it seems that the power point viewer always tries to repaint only the visible area that respects the aspect ratio of the content. I'm quite sure that this could be resolved at the C++ level, so it's possible that filing a bug report might solve the issue. Unfortunately, at this point in time (with Qt5 no more being actively updated for the open source release) submitting a report won't solve your issue even if it will be fixed (unless they decide to make another public release or you switch to PyQt6).

Comment: @humanbydefinition did you find a solution to your problem?